# How can I hide/show h2 and ul tags on the iphone?

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm having trouble getting an email blast to hide and display the h2 and ul tags. It works just fine in outlook and in most browser but on the iphone the display:block attribute is not respected. I also tried wrapping the content in a div tag and the attributes were ignored. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>WalkGreen&trade; Capabilities</title>
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<style type="text/css">


@media (max-width: 767px) {
  h2[class=hidden-xs], ul[class=hidden-xs] {
    display: none !important;
  }

}

/* Media Query for mobile */

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {  

    h2[class=visible-xs], ul[class=visible-xs] {
    display: block !important;
  }
  p[class=align-center]{text-align:left !important;}

/* This resizes tables and images to be 100% wide with a proportionate width */
    table[class=emailwrap], img[class=emailwrap]{width:100% !important; height:auto !important;}
    h2[class=mobile-pad]{padding-left:8px !important; padding-right:8px !important;}
    img[class=logo-sm]{width:35%;}
    img[class=img-mob]{width:90% !important; height:auto !important;}
    img[class=mbl-icon]{width: 32px !important; height:32px !important;}
    td[class=mbl-pad-1]{padding-left:16px !important; padding-right:16px !important;}
    td[class=mbl-pad-2]{padding-left:16px !important; padding-right:16px !important; text-align:left !important;}
    td[class=mbl-pad-3]{padding-top:16px;}
    td[class=border-off]{border-bottom:0 !important;}
    a[class=mbl-button]{webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; padding-top:10px !important; padding-right:10px !important; padding-bottom:10px !important; padding-left: 10px !important; font-size:18px !important;}

/* Hide stuff on mobiles */
    table[class=emailnomob],td[class=emailnomob],img[class=emailnomob],span[class=emailnomob]{display:none !important;}

    td[class=emailcolsplit]{width:100%!important; float:left!important;}

    a[class=emailmobbutton]{display:block !important;font-size:14px !important; font-weight:bold !important; padding:6px 4px 8px 4px !important; line-height:18px !important; background:#dddddd    !important; border-radius:5px !important; margin:10px auto;width:70%; text-align:center; color:#111 !important; text-decoration:none; text-shadow:#fff 1px 0 0 ;}

/* This resizes body text for mobiles */
    ul[class=emailbodytext],span[class=emailbodytext],a[class=emailbodytext] ,p[class=emailbodytext]{font-size:16px !important; line-height:21px !important;padding-right:16px !important;}
    h2[class=emailh2],span[class=emailh2],a[class=emailh2]{font-size:22px !important; line-height:26px !important;}
    td[class="mbl-header"]{padding-right:8px !important; padding-left:8px !important;}

}

</style>

</head>

<body style="background-color:#FFF;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!-- top disclaimer -->
                <table class="emailnomob" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; text-align:center; padding-top:8px; padding-right:8px; padding-bottom:8px; padding-left:8px; color:#999">
                            <span>TROUBLE SEEING SOMETHING? </span><a style="color:#999;" href="#">VIEW IT ONLINE</a> OR <a style="color:#999;" href="*|UNSUB|*">UNSUBSCRIBE</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!-- content begins -->
                <table class="emailwrap" style="background-color:#fff;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <!-- top banner -->
                            <table class="emailwrap" style="background-color:#fff;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>

<a href="http://www.walkgreenproducts.com/decking.html"><img class="emailwrap" src="images/top-banner2.gif" alt="Exotic Hardwood Decking, Rainscreen and Fencing" /></a>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- 3 column content -->
                            <table class="emailwrap" style="background-color:#fff;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="emailcolsplit" width="200" valign="top" align="center">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="mbl-pad-3">
                                                    <img src="images/products.gif" alt="Products" />
                                                    <h2  class="emailh2" style="font-size:18px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">Decking</h2>
                                                    <ul class="emailbodytext" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:14px;">
                                                        <li>Angelyn <br/> (1” x 5.5”) (7/8” x 5.5”)<br/> </li>
                                                        <li>Cumaru <br/> (1” x 5.5”) (1” x 3.5”) (7/8” x 5.5”)<br/> </li>
                                                        <li>Espresso Garapa <br/>  (7/8” x 5.5”)<br/> </li>
                                                        <li>Gold Garapa <br/> (1” x 5.5”) (7/8” x 5.5”)<br/> </li>
                                                        <li>Tigerwood <br/> (1” x 3.5”)<br/> </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                            <h2 class="visible-xs" style="font-size:18px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; display:none;"><span class="emailh2">Rainscreen & Siding</span></h2>
                                                            <ul class="visible-xs" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:14px; display:none;">
                                                                <li class="emailbodytext">Profiling for any hidden siding fastener system</li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                            <h2 class="visible-xs" style="font-size:18px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; display:none;"><span class="emailh2">Fencing</span></h2>
                                                            <ul class="visible-xs" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:14px; display:none">
                                                                <li class="emailbodytext">Fence Boards</li>
                                                            </ul>   

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="emailcolsplit" width="200" valign="top" align="center">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <img src="images/milling.gif" alt="Milling" />
                                                    <h2 class="emailh2" style="font-size:18px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">Custom Milling</h2>
                                                    <ul class="emailbodytext" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:14px;">
                                                        <li>Tongue & Groove</li>
                                                        <li>Siding Profiles</li>
                                                        <li>Edge Grooving for hidden fastening systems</li>
                                                        <li>Anti skid decking</li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="emailcolsplit" width="200" valign="top" align="center">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <img src="images/delivery.gif" alt="Delivery" />
                                                    <h2  class="emailh2" style="font-size:18px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">Options</h2>
                                                    <ul class="emailbodytext" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:14px;">
                                                        <li>Large Volumes</li>
                                                        <li>LTL</li> 
                                                        <li>Full Container or Trucks</li> 
                                                        <li>Contractor Packs</li>
                                                        <li>Special Orders</li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- 2 column content -->
                            <table class="emailwrap" style="background-color:#fff;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="emailcolsplit" width="200" valign="top" align="center">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <h2 class="hidden-xs" style="font-size:18px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">Rainscreen & Siding</h2>
                                                    <ul class="hidden-xs" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:14px;">
                                                        <li>Profiling for any hidden siding fastener system</li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>   
                                    <td class="emailcolsplit" width="200" valign="top" align="center">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <h2  class="hidden-xs" style="font-size:18px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">Fencing</h2>
                                                    <ul class="hidden-xs" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:14px;">
                                                        <li>Fence Boards</li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="emailcolsplit" width="200" valign="top" align="center">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><p class="align-center" style="text-align:right; margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0;"><img src="images/logos.gif" alt="US Greenbuilding Council, Rainforest Alliance, FSC Certificate" /></p></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- species heading -->
                            <table style="background-color:#4982a5;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center" >
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <img src="images/species.gif" alt="Species" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- species thumbnails -->
                            <table class="emailwrap" style="background-color:#fff;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-bottom:15px; padding-top:15px;" class="emailcolsplit" width="120" valign="top" align="center">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%">
                                            <a href="http://www.walkgreenproducts.com/decking_angelyn.html"><img class="emailwrap" src="images/angelyn.jpg "width="110" height="119" alt="Angelyn" /></a>
                                            <h2 class="emailh2" style="font-size:12px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; text-align:center;">Angelyn</h2>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding-bottom:15px; padding-top:15px;" class="emailcolsplit" width="120" valign="top" align="center">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%">
                                            <a href="http://www.walkgreenproducts.com/decking_cumaru.html"><img class="emailwrap" src="images/cumaru.jpg "width="110" height="119" alt="Cumaru" /></a>
                                            <h2 class="emailh2" style="font-size:12px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; text-align:center;">Cumaru</h2>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding-bottom:15px; padding-top:15px;" class="emailcolsplit" width="120" valign="top" align="center">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%">
                                            <a href="http://www.walkgreenproducts.com/decking_garapa.html"><img class="emailwrap" src="images/garapa.jpg "width="110" height="119" alt="Gold Garapa" /></a>
                                            <h2 class="emailh2" style="font-size:12px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; text-align:center;">Gold Garapa</h2>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding-bottom:15px; padding-top:15px;" class="emailcolsplit" width="120" valign="top" align="center">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%">
                                            <a href="http://www.walkgreenproducts.com/decking_espresso_garapa.html"><img class="emailwrap" src="images/espresso-garapa.jpg "width="110" height="119" alt="Espresso Garapa" /></a>
                                            <h2 class="emailh2" style="font-size:12px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; text-align:center;">Espresso Garapa</h2>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding-bottom:15px; padding-top:15px;" class="emailcolsplit" width="120" valign="top" align="center">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%">
                                            <a href="http://www.walkgreenproducts.com/decking_tigerwood.html"><img class="emailwrap" src="images/tigerwood.jpg "width="110" height="119" alt="Tigerwood" /></a>
                                            <h2 class="emailh2" style="font-size:12px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; text-align:center;">Tigerwood</h2>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- species content -->
                            <table class="emailwrap" style="background-color:#fff;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2 class="emailh2" style="font-size:18px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">We Have Over 500,000 Lineal Ft. of stock on the ground at all times, ready for prompt shipment! </h2>

                                        <p class="emailbodytext" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:14px;">WalkGreen&trade; maintains a philosophy of stewardship, product quality and client satisfaction by preserving forest ecology and forest-dependent communities while supporting responsible and legal forestry. WalkGreen&trade; remains competitively priced by holding the largest inventory of FSC&reg; Exotic Hardwood Decking and Rainscreen in North America. </p>

                                        <h2 class="emailh2"style="font-size:18px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">General Wood Specifications</h2>

                                        <p class="emailbodytext" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:14px;">All wood is Export A grade, three side clear with minor defect down side.  Kiln Dried to 12-15% moisture content. S4S E4E unless milled to specification. Random length 7-18 ft, odds and evens. 100% FSC® Certified</p>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- contact info -->
                            <table class="emailwrap" style="background-color:#fff; border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="emailcolsplit" width="475" valign="top" align="center">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding-top:12px; padding-bottom:12px;">
                                                    <h2 class="emailh2" style="font-size:15px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0;">Text</h2>

                                                </td>

                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="emailcolsplit" width="125" valign="top" align="center">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding-top:12px; padding-bottom:12px;">
                                                <a style="margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0;" href="#"> <img src="images/facebook.gif" alt="Like us on Facebook" /></a>
                                                <a style="margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0;" href="#"> <img src="images/web-graphic.gif" alt="WalkGreen Products Website" /></a>
                                                <a style="margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0;" href="#"><img src="images/mail.gif" alt="Contact Us" /></a></p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>                           
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- footer -->
                            <table class="emailwrap" style="background-color:#fff;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="emailcolsplit" width="250" valign="top" align="center">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; padding-right:20px;">
                                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/walkgreen.gif" alt="WalkGreen Products" /></a>

                                                </td>

                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="emailcolsplit" width="350" valign="top" align="center">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;">
                                                    <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#999;">IF YOU NO LONGER WISH TO RECEIVE EMAILS PLEASE <a style="color:#999;" href="*|UNSUB|*">UNSUBSCRIBE</a><br/>
                                                    &copy; 2015 WALKGREEN&trade; PRODUCTS, ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>                           
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please accept the answer, by clicking the tick button on my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bad Media Queries**

You have bad queries. i.e. an iphone6 plus is `max-device-width : 736px`, therefore not satisfying the latter query! See [media-queries-for-standard-devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

If you wish to fix this issue, you must first define what size is `xs`. It's not enough just to say ALL mobile phones, as some mobile phones have VERY big screen and look like tablets! Iphone 6 Plus is a prime example of a big phone.

If I understand this correctly:

- `hidden-xs` should hide the `h2` only for below a certain screen width and visible for the rest
- `visible-xs` should show the `h2` only for below a certain screen width and hidden for the rest

e.g. If you define `xs` as a screen width `<= 767px` then your CSS should be:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  /* styles for screen width <= 767px */
  h2[class=hidden-xs], ul[class=hidden-xs] {
     display: none;
  }

  h2[class=visible-xs], ul[class=visible-xs] {
     display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* screen width >= 768px */
  h2[class=hidden-xs], ul[class=hidden-xs] {
    display: block;
  }

  h2[class=visible-xs], ul[class=visible-xs] {
     display: none;
  }
}
```

or simplified to (mobile-first approach):

```
h2[class=hidden-xs], ul[class=hidden-xs] {
  display: none;
}

h2[class=visible-xs], ul[class=visible-xs] {
   display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* styles for screen width >= 768px */

  h2[class=hidden-xs], ul[class=hidden-xs] {
    display: block;
  }

  h2[class=visible-xs], ul[class=visible-xs] {
     display: none;
  }
}
```

or desktop first approach

```
h2[class=hidden-xs], ul[class=hidden-xs] {
   display: block;
}

h2[class=visible-xs], ul[class=visible-xs] {
   display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  /* styles for screen width <= 767px */
  h2[class=hidden-xs], ul[class=hidden-xs] {
     display: none;
  }

  h2[class=visible-xs], ul[class=visible-xs] {
     display: block;
  }
}
```

**Note: the `!important` is likely unnecessary**

Comment: That meta tag is present in my original html file I just did not include it in the source code I pasted in. The following is just a snippet from the email blast.

Comment: how about the header tag. Also can you reduce your code such that it has the minimal amount of code but still has the problem, and edit your question to reflect this fix please

Comment: I think I found the problem. I edited my answer. The issue is none of the queries are being run! What iphone are you using out of curiosity?

Comment: I have pasted in the original source code. Please look again.

Comment: I also added some more code to show you how to do this

Comment: The visible-xs small did work however hidden-xs did not: You can view the result here: http://walkgreenproducts.com/newsletter/capabilities/emailblast-temp.html

Comment: Sorry I was meant to write `display: none` NOT `display: hidden`. A quick glance at the web inspector should have shown you that `display: hidden` is not a valid property.

Comment: Everything works great in the browser. However when I import the html file into mailchimp the visible-xs does not appear to be working correctly. Could it be altering the code on import?

Comment: That seems to be more of a mailchimp issue or an issue with the email provider you are using (e.g. gmail), so they may be changing something. In that case I suggest asking a separate question specific to mail chimp, as they are probably changing something.

Comment: Will do that. Thanks for the help Yahya!

Comment: No problem. Please mark this as correct answer, by clicking the tick

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a class to hide elements that will not show on a phone

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px){
.hide_phone{display: none;}
}
```